# How to programmatically define a field of type yet-to-be fully defined in GraphQL-Java?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am "playing" with `graphql-java` and the related kickstarter servlet, modifying it to build the schema programmatically based on the types I discover automatically. The documentation is (almost) there but is outdated in spots and references deprecated methods. My particular issue is that the `GraphQLFieldDefinition.Builder` has four variants of the `type(...)` method - three accepting various (other) builders and one accepting the `GraphQLOutputType`, none of which I may have. Furthermore, those that accept builder actually invoke the `build()` method on those builders so I am anxious to pass any of my "unfinished" type builders either. I thought of defining all types upfront with no fields at all, then add fields to them after that but if `build()` gets called on these at that point in time, even if they don't get into an unwanted state today I can see how a future update may demand at most a single `build()` invocation.

So the question is how does one declare a field to yet-undefined or not fully defined type? For example, an `Employee`'s `manager` field being itself of the `Employee` type such as:

```
type Employee {
   name: String!
   manager: Employee
   reports: [Employee!]
   buddy: Employee
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think I may have found the answer - GraphQLTypeReference. Will check if this works before creating the answer (at this point no answers are given to me)

Comment: GraphQLTypeReference allows referencing but not nullability specification...

Comment: OK... GraphQLNonNull wrapper to the rescue for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in my comments, instead of attempting to (directly) use the builder or the built type one should create an instance of `GraphQLTypeReference` instead like so:

```java
GraphQLTypeReference.typeRef(typeName)
```

This will be resolved automatically when the schema is built.

Should we want to indicate that this is not nullable even if the referenced type is, we further need to wrap into a `GraphQLNonNull` wrapper like so:

```java
GraphQLNonNull.nonNull(typeRef)
```

... and use that as the type.